# How to read a byte from a file in elisp

Tags: file-io, elisp

Elisp has a lot of functions for manipulating *buffers* opened in the editor, but it doesn't seem to have any raw file operations. Maybe what I need is in there, but I'm missing it.

How do you open a stream and read bytes from it? The Common Lisp equivalent would be:

```
(defvar stream (open "example.txt" :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8)))
(defvar byte (read-byte stream))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that directly.
Either you read the file into a buffer (with `insert-file-contents`, which actually can also insert a subrange of the file's bytes), or otherwise you create a process that runs `cat` on the file.

Comment: Can `insert-file-contents` handle binary data?

Comment: Of course: that's the primitive that Emacs uses when you open a file, and Emacs of course can edit binary files.  If you don't want to rely on Emacs's auto-detection of coding-system, you can let-bind `coding-system-for-read` to `binary` around the call to `insert-file-contents`.